# Order 2 columns

Tags: sql

I have a table with Client and Date columns i omit others. How to order by client and by date..
when i try this query only the first column is ordered but i would like both of them. thank in advance

```
$qryz="SELECT * FROM claims_follow_up.reconciliation order by Posting_Date, Client_Name';
```

Comment: Change orderby clause to "order by Client_Name, Posting_Date"

Comment: i did it already client_name is ordered but posting_date is not..

Comment: Please post your table structures, example data, and the results that you are seeing (along with why you think they are wrong). You should also tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using. Finally, you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @branche, `posting_date` is ordered. If you have records of same `client_name`, you will see the `posting_date` order.